# Need help with the correct wording: Platoon? Squad? Or something else?

Tags: short-story, terminology

I wrote a short story about a 6 men on a rescue mission to save a family during WWII. I originally called them a "platoon" and wrote about the main characters "platoon mates"; however, I have since learned that a "Squad" is made of 7-14 men and a "Platoon" is supposedly made of 3-4 "squads".

I was wondering if anyone here was able to answer the question of which is the right wording (or even if either one is correct) for this small group of men on the rescue mission?

Thank You!

Comment: Military organization trees are easy research.  FWIW, this changes from army to army (US vs. British vs. WWI German vs. WWII German vs. modern German, for instance).  BTW, welcome to Writing Stack Exchange.  You should take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] to understand why this question is off topic here, and how this site works in general.

Comment: In "Saving Private Ryan" Cpt. Miller team of 8 men was routinely called a "squad".

Comment: Sorry about that. And thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group could either be a squad or a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(military_unit)), a grouping between squad and platoon.

Even in WW2, squads were not uniformly armed.  There would be rifle squads and machine gun squads and mortar squads. This kind of specialization was even continued up the organization with heavy weapon platoons and companies. This is mostly for logistics and training reasons. And, this is not to say that these specialized groups didn't contain rifle squads. They certainly did since they'd depend on riflemen to protect their positions.

All this is to say, is that a few squads from a company could be organized into a section for a specific mission that needed mostly riflemen, but also support: machine guns, mortars, bazookas or other anti-tank weapons. You'd have a designated section leader and assistant section leaders to maintain tactical control.

You can observe this combat structure outlined in the short stories of Ron Glass and  Hienlein's Starship Troopers.

Comment: Thank you!  And I must say, I need to recheck those stories because I never noticed that before (probably because I wasn't writing something needing that information at that time).  Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Squad is correct term and in the U.S. Army would have been commanded by a Staff Sergeant (Although this predates the NATO pay grade system for ranks, the modern rank is E-5).  Modern Squads are lead by a Sergeant [E-4].

For enlisted, Squad mates is a more defined concept as these are the small group you will do most of your work with.   Two squds will make a section, and two sections make a platoon.

Note, the size should also translate to the U.S. Marines, who use land based unit orgainzations but not the Navy or Coast Guard, where units are arranged more around ships than personnel.  U.S. Airforce was not a thing but the Army airforce would be arranged by number of planes.

Squads should not be confused with a Squadron, which in Armies is a company level cavalry unit (lead by a Lt. Colonel (O-6)).  Squadrons also exist in Navies (3-10 ships or an admin unit for a lone operating vessel such as a submarine, O-5 or O-6) and Air forces (12-24 planes, depending on the number of planes and including the ground crew.  Depending on the size, the commanding rank can range from O-4 to O-6).

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would still be squad. A squad could be 7-14 but in a typical U.S. Army it would be 6-10 men. Your six soldiers would still be a squad.

Comment: Thank you for your input!